# Sharing data created in an iOS iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I have done a fair amount of searching and haven't seen a detailed response to this question - apologies if I missed something though!

I have the situation where I am creating an iPad (iOS6) app which allows a user (call this the content-creation user) to generate content of various (relatively lightweight, but including photos) types.

I want others users to be able to "subscribe" to content created by the content-creation user, in a non-device specific way (they could get email alerts / notifications and so on, depending on their preferred device, e.g. web / apple device). They would only need read access to this data.

At the moment the content-creation user / app is storing content as CoreData objects locally. My understanding is that even if I moved these CoreData objects to iCloud it wouldn't be possible to selectively share the data with other users on different iTunes accounts (and especially to those accessing the data via the web).

The sort of approach I am thinking of is:

As content is created by the content-creation user persist it to some global generic data store (e.g. mySQL running on a webhost). A separate process could then be used to monitor this data store for updates and send relevant notifications to subscribed users, who could then fetch relevant data from the data store. If I took this approach, are there any out of the box solutions for syncing CoreData objects to a non-Apple specific type data store running on a webhost or something similar? Also something that went in the other direction in the case where the subscribed users had i-devices and so it would be useful to generate data on their device from the generic data store? Ideally I want to worry as little as possible about keeping the data in the content-creation users CoreData synced up with the generic data store, as I realize this is an area which could quickly become a complex mine field.

Are there better (or simpler) approaches to the above that I should consider? Any advice / tips very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sharing data as you're describing I'd recommend the Parse.com service (http://www.parse.com).  It's free, and allows you to create objects that can be accessed by others given the correct authorization.

There's a lovely iOS wrapper for the service [here](https://github.com/adelevie/parse_resource).  They parse.com site also has good documentation.

I use it to allow users to store data in one place yet access it from any device.  It would work well in your case I think.